# Error with SPARQL on Rstudio

Tags: r, xml, uri, sparql, rdf

I'm using the sparql package in Rstudio, to query OMIM through bio2rdf. I have tested my query in yasgui and it works correctly. But from Rstudio he returns the following error:

```
> qde <- SPARQL(endpoint,query)
Opening and ending tag mismatch: hr line 5 and body
Opening and ending tag mismatch: body line 3 and html
Premature end of data in tag html line 1
Error: 1: Opening and ending tag mismatch: hr line 5 and body
2: Opening and ending tag mismatch: body line 3 and html
3: Premature end of data in tag html line 1
```

Thanks!!

Comment: which query? which endpoint? looks like HTML format is returned, sure that you used the correct URL? It must **not** be the YASGUI URL

Comment: my query is too long for paste here sry

Comment: ok, but then I don't see how somebody could help you...try a smaller query first. then check the endpoint URL - more can't be done

Comment: my query is too long to post it in the comments, but the same query with fewer attributes does not produce any error.
If I modify the call to the SPARQL function so that it returns a csv table, it returns an empty table with the content: 414 Request-URI Too Large

Comment: Ok, then you got the answer. Virtuoso has some limit on the size of the query when running a GET request. You could try a POST request. See discussion [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/virtuoso/mailman/message/33714991/)

Comment: Sry but i didn´t know how to POST instead of GET from SPARQL Package in Rstudio, i try this: qde <- SPARQL(endpoint,querye,update = "LOAD",curl_args=list(style="post"))
and i get the same error

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on RStudio a while ago.
This problem was package dependencies.
You do install the "sparql" package and its dependencies as below.

`install.packages(c("SPARQL", "XML", "RCurl"))`

It would be great if you could run the below sample code.

```
d <- SPARQL(url="http://statistics.data.gov.uk/sparql",
            query="SELECT * WHERE { ?s ?p ?o . } LIMIT 10",
            ns=c('time','<http://www.w3.org/2006/time#>'))
is.data.frame(d$results)
head(d$results)
```

I hope it useful for you.