# How to do POST instead of GET with the SPARQL package from Rstudio

Tags: r, sparql

What are the parameters or syntax for using a POST instead of a GET request in the SPARQL R package?

I tried this:

```
> qde <- SPARQL(endpoint,querye,update = "LOAD",curl_args=list(method="post"))
Opening and ending tag mismatch: hr line 5 and body
Opening and ending tag mismatch: body line 3 and html
Premature end of data in tag html line 1
Error: 1: Opening and ending tag mismatch: hr line 5 and body
2: Opening and ending tag mismatch: body line 3 and html
3: Premature end of data in tag html line 1
In addition: Warning message:
In mapCurlOptNames(names(.els), asNames = TRUE) :
Unrecognized CURL options: method
```

Comment: From the docs: "If the parameter "query" is given, it is assumed the given query is a SELECT query and
a GET request will be done to get the results from the URL of the end point. Otherwise, if the
parameter "update" is given, it is assumed the given query is an update query and a POST request
will be done to send the request to the URL of the end point."

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50346119/error-with-sparql-on-rstudio (?) Duplicate.